# dynamic content update problem in streamlit

Tags: python, nlp, project, reload, streamlit

i have an array of paragraphs and two buttons abs+ , abs- . when i click on abs+ the next index para should be visible and when i click on abs- , previous para should be visible. but when i click abs+ / abs - button the page reloads and stucks and even previous computation’s outputs are vanished

```
import streamlit as st
from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi
from Summerize import transcribe, detect_language, translate_large_text, recursive_summarize, summarize_paragraph, identify_key_phrases, highlight_key_phrases
#from  import Server

def main():
    st.title("Video Summarizer Tool")

    # Input box for users to input the URL
    videourl = st.text_input("Enter YouTube Video URL:")
    videoid = videourl.split("/")[-1]
    st.session_state["current_index"] = 0 

    if st.button("Process Video"):
        st.info("Processing video... This may take some time.")

        try:
            transcript_list = YouTubeTranscriptApi.list_transcripts(videoid)
            all_languages = ["hi", "bn", "te", "ta", "mr", "en", "es", "fr", "de", "zh-Hans", 'ar']

            total_content = ''
            for transcript in transcript_list:
                if transcript.language_code in all_languages:
                    captions = transcript.fetch()
                    for segment in captions:
                        if segment['text'] != '':  # Skip empty segments
                            total_content += segment['text'] + ' '
            
            detected_language = detect_language(total_content)

            if detected_language:
                st.success(f"The detected language is: {detected_language}")
                if detected_language != 'en':
                    total_content = translate_large_text(total_content, src_language=detected_language)
                    st.success(f"Translated text to English:\n{total_content}")

            # Transcribe the video if no transcript is available
            if not total_content:
                total_content = transcribe(videourl)
                st.success(f"Transcribed text:\n{total_content}")

            st.subheader("Summarization and Key Phrases Extraction")
            all_summaries = recursive_summarize(total_content)
            
            current_index = st.session_state["current_index"]
            
            

            
            st.write(all_summaries[current_index])

            if st.button('abstract +'):
                if 0<= current_index< len(all_summaries)-1:
                    st.session_state["current_index"] = current_index + 1
                else:
                    st.markdown('cannot compress more',unsafe_allow_html=True)
            
            if st.button('abstract -'):
                if current_index == 0:
                    st.markdown('cannot be more detailed',unsafe_allow_html= True)
                else:
                    st.session_state["current_index"] = current_index - 1




            result = summarize_paragraph(all_summaries[-1], num_sentences=5)
            key_phrases = identify_key_phrases(all_summaries[-1], min_length=2, max_length=4)

            if key_phrases is not None:
                st.subheader("Key Phrases:")
                st.text(', '.join(key_phrases))

                st.subheader("Highlighted Summary:")
                for i, sentence in enumerate(result, 1):
                    st.write(f"{i}. {highlight_key_phrases(sentence, key_phrases)}",unsafe_allow_html=True)

        except Exception as e:
            st.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

this is my code , someone please help !

`

i tried using session state but that didnt work, tried changing st.write to st.markdown even that didnt work.  all i want is to update the space where current para is being displayed to next para or previous para when i click on those buttons without page reload